# Open Custom Context Menu outside of parent DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, contextmenu

```js
class Menu {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
    this.callEvent();
  }

  callEvent() {
    this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click', () => {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    });
  }
}

const menu = new Menu();
```

```css
#parent-div{
border: 2px solid green;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="parent-div"> 
<table>
<tbody>
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="context-menu">
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 1</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 2</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 3</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 4</a>   
  </div>
</div>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have created a custom context menu and incorporated Bootstraps drop down classes from their menu items section. Right now my context menu opens and closes properly on click, the issue is that the context menu is changing the size of the parent div that it is inside of (understandable). Is it possible to open the context menu div outside of the parent div, preferably a little off to the right?

HTML

```
<div>
    <table id="my-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="column-1"><h4></h4>
                <h5>
                    <a href="">Link 1</a>
                </h5>
                <p>September 17, 2020 - September 24, 2020</p>
            </td>
            <td class="column-2">
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v pull-right" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                </i>
                <div class="menu dropdown show">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical dropdown-menu" role="group" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" style="">
                        <a href="#" type="button"
                          class="btn dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
                        <a href="#" type="button"
                           class="btn dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Extracted context menu html from above. This is the menu I want to have show outside of the parent div:

```
<div class="menu dropdown show">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical dropdown-menu"role="group" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <a href="#" type="button" class="btn dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#" type="button" class="btn dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
class Menu {
    constructor() {
        this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
        this.callEvent();
    }

    callEvent() {
        this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click',this.showMenu.bind(this));
    }

    showMenu(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    }
}

var menu = new Menu();
```

CSS

```
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: please create code snippet using stackoverflow's inbuilt code snippet tool to provide a working example for people to look at, it will make it easier for others to help solve your problem

Comment: you'll want to make the context menu `position: absolute` which removes it from the document flow and won't affect the sizing or position of siblings or parent.

Comment: @Capagris I added a code snippet. You will notice that when you click on the ellipsis, there is a menu of sorts that opens within the parent div, I want that menu to open outside of the parent div. You will also notice that the context menu I want to have open outside of the parent div lives 3 levels deep.

Comment: @pilchard I added position absolute to my menu in the css but now when I click the ellipsis, I can't see my context menu anymore

Comment: I have edited your snippet in my answer. You need to also set the parent's position to `position: relative` and then adjust it's position relative to the parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to position your menu using `position: absolute` with the parent's position set to `position: relative`. This removes the menu from the document flow and allows you to position it relative to the parent using `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` css properties.

I have edited your snippet by adding the following CSS

```
#parent-div{
border: 2px solid green;

position: relative;     /* accommodates absolutely positioned children */
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  
  width: 80px;         /* set menu width */
  height: 60px;        /* set menu height */
  position: absolute;  /* position absolute relative to parent */
  bottom: -90px;       /* position the menu relative to parents bottom edge*/
}
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById('toggle-absolute');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
   menu.classList.toggle('absolute');
  });
```

```css
.container {
  background: aquamarine;
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

#menu {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <p>I'm a menu</p>
  </div>
  <button type='button' id='toggle-absolute'>Toggle Absolute</button>

</div>
```

```js
class Menu {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    this.ellipsis = document.querySelector('.fa.fa-ellipsis-v');
    this.callEvent();
  }

  callEvent() {
    this.ellipsis.addEventListener('click', () => {
      $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    });
  }
}

const menu = new Menu();
```

```css
#parent-div{
border: 2px solid green;

position: relative;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="parent-div"> 
<table>
<tbody>
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="context-menu">
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 1</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 2</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 3</a>
     <a href="#" type="button">Item 4</a>   
  </div>
</div>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: when I try to implement your code THe context menu still opens inside the parent div and then it just creates scroll bars. Why would this be? Could it be that I am applying the parent styling to the wrong div?

Comment: It's possible. The element with `position: absolute` will be positioned relative to it's nearest parent with `position: relative`. In my example I applied `position: relative` to `#parent-div` so it escapes the flow from the point of that div down.

Comment: if you do I created  a room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221382/context-menu-positioning